# Prove absolute value inequality

Tags: discrete-mathematics, absolute-value

Prove that for every two real numbers x and y, it is true that $\vert x\vert + \vert y\vert\ge\vert x - y\vert$. Show that there exist real numbers for which $\vert x\vert + \vert y\vert = \vert x - y\vert$.

I don't quite know the right way to prove this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: $|x|+|-y|\geq|x-y|$ by triangle inequality, and $|-y|=|y|$.$$|0|+|0|=|0-0|$$

Answer (score 0):

$|x|+|-y|\geq|x-y|$ by the triangle
inequality, as already stated by @Don Thousand

$\vert x\vert + \vert y\vert = \vert x - y\vert$ is always the case for numbers with $x  \ge -y \ge 0$, or the same with $x$ and $y$ exchanged.